# How to navigate clion code completion drop-down menu (other than arrow keys)?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, clion

Clion and other Intellij platforms offer automatic code completion suggestions.  You can accept a suggestion using Tab, and navigate suggestions using the arrow keys.  Arrow keys are pretty inconvenient because they are so far from the home row.

Is there another way?  Can the navigate keys be rebound.  This is not mentioned in the code completion documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the Up/Down and other actions in the IDE Keymap settings. They will work in the completion popup as well. You may also consider IdeaVim plug-in.

[image: keymap]